# Cannot click button in nightmare.js but works in console

Tags: javascript, electron, dom-events, nightmare

I've successfully navigated to the corresponding page where I want to select multiple elements and click a button to confirm. The selection of the elements work, I've confirmed this with a screenshot, but clicking the button in nightmare does not work. When I run the segment in the console, everything works fine. The button has a randomly defined ID, and everything else except the innerHTML of the button is not unique, so I iterate over all buttons to match it based on content.

It's this snippet that's relevant.

```
.evaluate(function(){
        //Select all the "elements" for room.
        var elemArr = document.getElementById("L210").getElementsByTagName("td");
        document.getElementById("resRoom").innerHTML = "L210";
        document.getElementById("resStartTime").innerHTML = "08:00";
        document.getElementById("resEndTime").innerHTML = "19:00";
        for(var i = 0; i < elemArr.length; i++){
            elemArr[i].className += " selected"
        }
        //Here select and click the button
        var bTags = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
        var searchText = "Confirm";
        for (var i = 0; i < bTags.length; i++) {
            if (bTags[i].innerHTML == searchText) {
                bTags[i].click();
                break;
            }
        }       
    })
```

Comment: Electron, it's nightmare 2.6.1. I've updated the question tags.

Comment: Are you sure that you waited enough for the click to take effect?

Comment: Yes, we've tried waiting two seconds. When we run the code as is in the browser console (of course, not with the nightmare specific code) it works fine without any waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your full code I can't say for sure, but the most likely answer is that in the context of evaluate your nightmare code ( the .click() ) won't run because it doesn't have access to the original nightmare function. You would either need to use `nightmare.click("bTags[i]")` or use 
`.then(function(result){
  if(result === "Confirm"){
    nightmare.click("bTags[i])"
  }`

On top of all this - you're using a for loop to call a nightmare action! This is going to cause some issues. Nightmare issues promises before executing. This means you're attempting to run multiple electron instances at the same time, because the promises execute concurrently with the for loop. Rather than queue up - they fight for dominance, causing a crash. You should probably use a generator to manage async code such as vo or co.

Resources:
[Common nightmare.js pitfalls](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/async-operations-loops.md)